# What is a good algorithm to predict volatility in metals commodity markets?

Tags: volatility, time-series, forecasting, machine-learning, commodities

I'm trying to create a script to predict major swings in the price of Aluminium.  I am trying to implement a dynamic time warping algorithm for the same.  Was wondering if this really is the best approach, or if there are some key items that I am missing.